# Matching alternating alphanumeric characters with regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to match the following alphanumeric combinations using regex; `ao1 a12 01p p1p 1ap 1p1`.

With the [following regex](https://regexr.com/41qod) I can match all but `p1p and 1p1`:

`[a-z][0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{1,2}[a-z]|[a-z][0-9][a-z]|[a-z]{1,2}[0-9]|[0-9][a-z][0-9]`

How do I match the alternating `number/letter/number` and `letter/number/letter` correctly using regular expressions? It needs to match precisely 3 characters, they occur within sentences.

Comment: Do you mean to match `[a-z0-9]{3}`? `\b[a-z0-9]{3}\b`? `(?<!\S)[a-z0-9]{3}(?!\S)`? Or even `(?<!\S)(?=[a-z]{0,2}\d)(?=\d{0,2}[a-z])[a-z\d]{3}(?!\S)`?

Comment: Can you provide an example output? Like what do you want from the cases where the string begins with a 0 as in `01p`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks :).

Comment: Which one exactly ? :)

Comment: The last one, `(?<!\S)(?=[a-z]{0,2}\d)(?=\d{0,2}[a-z])[a-z\d]{3}(?!\S)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!\S)(?=[a-z]{0,2}\d)(?=\d{0,2}[a-z])[a-z\d]{3}(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bGOUGK/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a whitespace or start of string should be immediately to the left of the current location
- `(?=[a-z]{0,2}\d)` - there must be a digit after 0 to 2 letters immediately to the right of the current location
- `(?=\d{0,2}[a-z])` - there must be a letter after 0 to 2 digits immediately to the right of the current location
- `[a-z\d]{3}` - three letters or digits are matched
- `(?!\S)`  - a whitespace or end of string should be immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor, exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like below?

[([\d][a-zA-Z][\d]|[a-zA-Z][\d][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]{2}[\d]|[a-zA-Z][\d]{2}|[\d]{2}[a-zA-Z]|[\d][a-zA-Z]{2})](https://regexr.com/420eo)

Comment: I should have mentioned, I was looking to match word boundaries as well, i need to fetch them from sentences of words, an only combinations of exactly three characters. Wiktor's solution does that exactly, even though yours matches my example :).

Comment: OK. Got it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

So if you need number/letter/number and letter/number/letter the below should work. But your input ao1 doesn't match this criteria.

```
\d[a-z]\d|[a-z]\d[a-z]
```